# jQuery Mask Plugin Can't start with letter 'S'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I want to use a mask to an input to start with `SP` and also `PT`. The `PT` input works fine, but the `SP` does not. Note that this is not my real code, it's just an example.

```js
$('#partshort').mask('SP-00000000000');
$('#svpshort').mask('PT-00000000000');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Problems with jQuery Mask Plugin?</h3>
  <p>Exemplify your problem here :-)</p>
  <hr />
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date-field">Example 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partshort">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ip-field">Example 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="svpshort">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/1wjbysnm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `S` character in the Mask library has a special meaning:

> By default, jQuery Mask Plugin only recognizes the logical digit A (Numbers and Letters) and S (A-Za-z) but you can extend or modify this behaviour

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation

To fix your issue you can simply remove the `S` character translation so that it behaves as any standard character:

```js
$('#partshort').mask('SP-00000000000', {
  translation: { S: null }
});
$('#svpshort').mask('PT-00000000000');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Problems with jQuery Mask Plugin?</h3>
  <p>Exemplify your problem here :-)</p>
  <hr />
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date-field">Example 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partshort">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ip-field">Example 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="svpshort">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Kinda regrads, André Gonçalves